# Cannot install GD on centos 5.8

Tags: perl, centos, gd

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgd.so when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgd.a when searching for -lgd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgd
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.so] Error 1
  /usr/bin/make  -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I'm trying to install GD.pm on centos 5.8 and stuck on this problem. I have already installed all available graphic libraries with yum. 
Have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GD module is just a thin layer around libgd. So you'll want to install that first.

```
$ sudo yum install gd
```

You'll probably need the development library too (for the C header files).

```
$ sudo yum install gd-devel
```

But, all in all, you're probably better off just installing the Centos package (which will handle all the dependencies for you).

```
$ sudo yum install perl-GD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I just missed gd-devel, thought that install everything but it was mistake.