# GD module on Heroku fails to install for a perl app

Tags: perl, heroku, dancer

I'm trying to deploy on Heroku a Dancer2 app that uses [`Authen::Captcha`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Authen::Captcha), which needs the [`GD`](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD) module which also needs the libgd2-xpm-dev package.

My application fails to push on Heroku with this error message :

```
remote:        ! Configure failed for GD-2.56. See /app/.cpanm/work/1468427280.295/build.log for details.
remote:        ! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'GD' is not installed
remote:        ! Bailing out the installation for Authen-Captcha-1.024.
 ! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'GD' is not installed, Module 'Authen::Captcha' is not installed
remote:        ! Bailing out the installation for ..
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Perl/PSGI app
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: `GD` depends on `libgd`, so you may need to install [some other package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014192)

Answer (score 0):

I could not install the  required  `libgd` packages on Heroku so I worked around the problem using as alternatives for `Authen::Captcha` either 
 `Dancer::Plugin::reCAPTCHA` or  `WebService::CaptchasDotNet`.